# Uniform convergence of a complex power series on a compact set

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need to prove that the complex power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ converges uniformly on the compact disc $|z| \leq r|z_0|,$ assuming that the series converges for some $z_0 \neq 0.$

*I know that the series converges absolutely for every $z,$ such that $|z|<|z_0|.$ Since $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz_0^n$ converges, by definition of convergence this means that the tail part of the series can be made arbitrarily small. So $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_nz_0^n = 0$ and this means that $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ so that $|a_nz_0^n| \leq M$ for $n \geq M.$ So it follows that $$|a_nz^n| \leq M \left|\dfrac{z}{z_0}\right|^n.$$ Thus $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_nz^n| \leq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}M \left|\dfrac{z}{z_0}\right|^n = M\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n,$$ where $r<1$ (because $|z|<|z_0| \implies \left|\dfrac{z}{z_0}\right|<1.$)*

But how do I get started on this uniform convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assume from the beginning that $r<1$. Then your argument proves that
$$
|z|\le r|z_0|\implies |a_n\,z^n|\le M\,r^n.
$$
The Weierstrass $M$-test shows that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Is the $r$ from both arguments interchangeable?

Comment: $r$ is a given in the statement of the problem. What you have proved is that the series converges pointwise on $\{|z|<|z_0|\}$ using that $|z/z_0|$ (which you call $r$) is less than one. But in your proof $r$ can be arbitrarely close to one.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your brief answer. Do you mind expanding it?

Comment: What is it you do not understand? I just used your computations, and then applied the [Weierstrass $M$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Comment: I am not saying that. The statement of the problem says to prove uniform convergence on the set $\{|z|\le r\,|z_0|\}$. It does not say $r<1$, but it should.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks.